# primary key column needs to be Auto incremented in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have created a below table in postgresql:

```
create table retail_fact( id serial not null, name text);
```

I have customer table in hive and MySQL and I want to load the data from them to PostgreSQL `retail_fact` table using Pentaho pdi (connecting through presto).

Also, O want the id to auto-increment in Postgres while I load the table with data from Hive and MySQL (in easier terms. i need an sql query to do the same).

The query is something like below:

```
insert into postgresql.rpt.order_fact(

select name from hive.retail.customer_hive
UNION
select name from mysql.retail.customer_mysql

);
```

while i insert the above data for name column into order_fact in postgres, how do i make the id column auto increment?

Answer (score 0):

Your table construct doesn't look much like PostgreSQL...  maybe MS SQL Server or Sybase, but that aside.  If you are using PostgreSQL and are on version 9.x, then a serial implements a sequence/default value behind the scenes.  I think on 10.x it's different, but on 9.x, you could simply hijack the sequence on your insert:

```
insert into postgresql.rpt.order_fact
with results as (
  select name from hive.retail.customer_hive
  UNION
  select name from mysql.retail.customer_mysql
)
select
  nextval('retail_fact_id_seq'), name
from results;
```

I'm assuming the CTE is necessary, otherwise the unique sequence values would turn your `union` into a `union all`.

Or, better yet (and more portable), specify the field(s) explicitly in your insert:

```
insert into postgresql.rpt.order_fact (name)
select name from hive.retail.customer_hive
UNION
select name from mysql.retail.customer_mysql
```

Comment: The `create table` in the question is perfectly fine for Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name -- sorry, I was referring to the table constructs of <database>.<schema>.<table> in the **query** not the create table but that's because I didn't read the question well enough -- he indicated it was migrating from a MySQL database, which explained it.